# how to use a loop with the function pgr_dijkstra

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, gis, postgis, pgrouting

I want to use a loop to calculate the distance traveled between two nodes 152   and 17720  (I use the function pgr_dijkstra) by deleting each time a cell. A cell contains several road links. the grid_edges_routard table contains the road links and the corresponding cell.
Iwant to have for each blocked cell the distance traveled between the two nodes.
I must use pgr_dijkstra to display in a second time the links traveled.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dist_grid() 
 RETURNS TABLE (
 celref_blocked INT,
 dist INT
) AS $$
DECLARE 
    var_r record;
BEGIN
 FOR var_r IN(SELECT distinct(cellule)as cel from grid_edges_routard )  
 LOOP

 SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target,cost 
                    FROM road_routard.edges_vulnerabilite 
                    where id not in (select edge_id
                                                     from grid_edges_routard
                                                     where cellule=var_r)  ',152   ,17720, FALSE)
                 where edge=-1; 
     celref_blocked  := var_r.cel ;            

        RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select get_dist_grid()
```

I have an error message: ERROR: column « var_r »  does not exist.
I use postgresql 9.5.

Comment: In your select query try '||var_r||' where you have  cellule=var_r

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed select query <pre>select edge_id
                                                     from grid_edges_routard
                                                     where cellule='||var_r||')  ',152   ,17720, FALSE) <code> but I got another error message ERROR: the request has no destination for the resulting data
HINT: If you want to cancel the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT: PL / pgsql function get_dist_grid0 (), line 8 to SQL statement

Comment: Define a new variable (var_q) of type record, then Execute your select query into your defined variable like this Execute 'SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(''SELECT id, source, target,cost FROM road_routard.edges_vulnerabilite where id not in (select edge_id from grid_edges_routard where cellule='''||var_r||''') '',152 ,17720, FALSE) where edge=-1' into var_q

Comment: This might give some errors as we have to escape the quotes for inner query, Try escaping quotes if it doesn't work and then you can use the out of the query in similar way as you have used celref_blocked := var_r.cel

Comment: Thank you very much it worked except that I wanted to have two columns resulting RETURNS TABLE (
 celref_blocked INT,
 dist float
) but I had only one column containing both results as (celref_blocked, dist)

Comment: Execute 'SELECT agg_cost FROM pgr_dijkstra(''SELECT id, source, target,cost 
     FROM road_routard.edges_vulnerabilite2 
     where id not in (select edge_id 
           from grid_edges_routard2 
           where cellule='||var_r||') '',70 ,50, FALSE) where edge=-1' into dist;  
     celref_blocked  := var_r.cel ;            

        RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

Comment: Finally it works. Thank you Arun

Comment: Welcome rihab.. do up vote the answer.

Comment: How can I vote. It's the first time I use stackoverflow

Comment: Just click the up arrow on the side of comment

Comment: unfortunately to vote I need at least 15 reputation while I am a new member on stack overflow.

Comment: I have added the our comments as answer to this question now you can up vote it and select it as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new variable (var_q) of type record, then Execute your select query into your defined variable like this `Execute 'SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(''SELECT id, source, target,cost FROM road_routard.edges_vulnerabilite where id not in (select edge_id from grid_edges_routard where cellule='||var_r||') '',152 ,17720, FALSE) where edge=-1' into var_q`
This might give some errors as we have to escape the quotes for inner query, Try escaping quotes if it doesn't work and then you can use the out of the query in similar way as you have used celref_blocked := var_r.cel